# iOS 7 Addressbook and NSMutableArray with UITableView getting name and number

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, ios7, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutable array and a UITableview that adds numbers from the address book. Just adding and removing the numbers works fine.  Ive created a custom table cell with the idea of displaying both a contact name and number. Again I can display a number on it fine.

I'm unsure how to also add the contacts name to the NSMutable array, (I'm not sure its possible - from googling around)

To pick my contacts I am using the code snippet in Apples dev guide  [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1)

Please can someone point me in the correct direction? Example or tutorial.

Comment: You have the phone numbers in an array but can't put the names in a array?

Comment: Yes I have the phone numbers in an array. I would like to know if i can add the contact name to the same array or would I have to create  a new array/do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add another NSMutableArray and I was getting errors with a "*null*" contact when picked.

After some head scratching and Googleing without a solid answer I edited a contact and found that some of my contacts had just a last name and some just a first - my contacts have been imported from an Android device and a Windows Phone. The contacts that I created on the Iphone worked perfectly.

I came up with this code to resolve the issue, adding first and last name strings together. If one was empty I add a blank.

```
NSString* firstname = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                                    kABPersonFirstNameProperty);


NSString* lastname = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                                kABPersonLastNameProperty);

NSString* name;


if (firstname == Nil) {
    firstname = @"";
}

if (lastname == Nil) {
    lastname = @"";
}

name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];
```

I did expect "*ABRecordCopyCompositeName*" to provide a friendly name but for me that still came back with null.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are able to get the phone numbers, I am assuming that you already know how to get the references to ABRecordRefs. To get the full name of an ABRecordRef, you have to use this method:

```
ABRecordCopyCompositeName( recordRef );
```

This returns a CFStringRef, which can be `__bridge`ed to an NSString for use in the table view.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Once I have the name and number can I add them both to my NSMutableArray? I would like to display both in a cell of my table

Comment: What you could do is have an array of arrays. Like `@[ @[@"Full Name", @"PhoneNum"]];`